# Nesting C# object initialization in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a C# function (`MyFunction(List<SafeInfo> securitySchema)`).  I'm trying to write a powershell script that will create the `List<SafeInfo>` object and pass it into `MyFunction(List<SafeInfo>)` via reflection.  Reflection's all good in PowerShell, but I'm trying to figure out the correct way to transpose the creation of the argument object into PowerShell.

Here's asample C# object that can be used:

```
List<SafeInfo> schema = new List<SafeInfo>() {
    new SafeInfo("mySafe1", new SecurityInfo("key1", SecurityType.Key, "some description")),
    new SafeInfo("mySafe2", new SecurityInfo("key2", SecurityType.Combination, "another description")),
    new SafeInfo("mySafe3", SecurityInfo.Unsecured)
};
```

My PowerShell so far:

```
$schema = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.List[MyNamespace.SafeInfo]'
$schema.Add(New-Object('MyNamespace.SafeInfo', 'mySafe1', New-Object('MyNamespace.SecurityInfo', 'key1', SecurityType.Key, 'some description')))
$schema.Add(New-Object('MyNamespace.SafeInfo', 'mySafe2', New-Object('MyNamespace.SecurityInfo', 'key2', SecurityType.Combination, 'another description')))
$schema.Add(New-Object('MyNamespace.SafeInfo', 'mySafe3', [MyNamespace.SecurityInfo]::Unsecured))
```

Am I on the right track?  What's the best way to create this nested object in PowerShell?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Am I on the right track?

Yes and no.

`New-Object` is a `cmdlet`, and `cmdlet` parameters are *space*-separated (and named) rather than comma-separated arguments like in C#.

Furthermore, with `New-Object` the type name and the argument list is two separate parameters

```
New-Object -TypeName 'MyNamespace.SafeInfo' -ArgumentList 'mySafe1',([MyNamespace.SecurityInfo]::Unsecured)
```

(notice how you can not resolve the static member `Unsecured` directly in the list, thus the `()` around)

You can't call a `cmdlet` directly inside a .NET method, but you can wrap the call in a subexpression (`$()`):

```
$schema.Add($(New-Object -TypeName 'MyNameSpace.SafeInfo' -ArgumentList 'mySafe1',$(New-Object -TypeName 'MyNameSpace.SafeInfo' -ArgumentList "key1", SecurityType.Key, "some description")))
```

If a parameter supports positional binding (as does `-TypeName` and `-ArgumentList`), you can omit the parameter name:

```
$schema.Add($(New-Object 'MyNameSpace.SafeInfo' 'mySafe1',$(New-Object 'MyNameSpace.SafeInfo' "key1",SecurityType.Key,"some description")))
```

Again, notice how the first parameter value (`'MyNameSpace'`) and the second (the argument list) is separated by a **space** rather than a comma

---

With the above in mind, your examples become:

```
$schema = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.List[MyNamespace.SafeInfo]'
$schema.Add($(New-Object 'MyNamespace.SafeInfo' 'mySafe1',$(New-Object 'MyNamespace.SecurityInfo' 'key1',([MyNamespace.SecurityType]::Key),'some description')))
$schema.Add($(New-Object 'MyNamespace.SafeInfo' 'mySafe2',$(New-Object 'MyNamespace.SecurityInfo' 'key2',([MyNamespace.SecurityType]::Combination),'another description')))
$schema.Add($(New-Object 'MyNamespace.SafeInfo' 'mySafe3',([MyNamespace.SecurityInfo]::Unsecured)))
```